# No comprendo el planteamiento

Tags: python

No comprendo del todo el resultado que arroja el ejemplo de este ejercicio:

> dadas dos matrices de cadenas a1 y a2, devolver una matriz ordenada
> en orden lexicográfico de las cadenas de `a1` que son subcadenas de
> cadenas de `a2`.

y como ejemplo tengo esto:

```
a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]

a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
```

resultado

```
["arp", "live", "strong"]
```

Entiendo lo del orden lexicográfico, pero no el resultado que da.

Sólo quiero entender la relación entre las cadenas `a1` y `a2` para entender el resultado (nada de código).

Comment: Hay que leer con más detemiento: "arp" es subcadena de "harp" y "sharp", por lo que estará en el resultado. "live" es subcadena de "lively" y "alive", etc, etc. No creo que sea un problema de javascript ni de python.

Answer (score 1):

Es más fácil expresarlo en un código que tratar de describirlo.

Lo que te piden es esto:

```
a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
resultado = set()

for palabra in a1:
    print(f"Palabra a buscar: {palabra}")
    for otra_palabra in a2:
        print(f"  Examinando {otra_palabra}", end="")
        if palabra in otra_palabra:
            print(" cumple!")
            resultado.add(palabra)
        else:
            print()

print(sorted(resultado))
```

El ejercicio es simplemente revisar si una palabra (de `a1`) es parte de otra (de `a2`). Para eso usamos la búsqueda de una subcadena dentro de otra:

```
        if palabra in otra_palabra:
```

Si la condición se cumple, entonces agregamos la palabra al conjunto de salida. Nótese que usamos un `set` en lugar de una lista, para automáticamente eliminar los duplicados.

Revisando la ejecución veras como toma cada palabra de `a1` y la busca en cada palabra de `a2`

```
Palabra a buscar: arp
  Examinando lively
  Examinando alive
  Examinando harp cumple!
  Examinando sharp cumple!
  Examinando armstrong
Palabra a buscar: live
  Examinando lively cumple!
  Examinando alive cumple!
  Examinando harp
  Examinando sharp
  Examinando armstrong
Palabra a buscar: strong
  Examinando lively
  Examinando alive
  Examinando harp
  Examinando sharp
  Examinando armstrong cumple!
['arp', 'live', 'strong']
```

Comment: AAAAAA ya me hace mas sentido, gracias Candid Moe